# Specify more than two rows in Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, rows

this is part of my code:

```
    temp1(i)=strread(temp);
    perme(:,i)=data([12 100],2);

    hold on
end

plot(temp1,perme);
```

and it works great, but when I need to specify more rows in `data` matrix (i.e. `data([12 50 80 100],2);`) I get some error:

```
??? Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch.
```

how can I select more rows in data ?!

Thank you so much..

Comment: Before you run this code, what are the sizes of `perme` and `data`?

Comment: perme=2*31, data=101*3... this sizes are when code run good

Comment: You're trying to change one column in `perme`, which only has two rows, so you can only specify two values from `data`.

Comment: Thus: `size(perme(:,i))` would be `2x1` and `size(data([12 50 80 100],2))`, `4x1`. This is why you get the error. Either initialize `perme` before your loop (like `perme = zeros(4,31)`) or at least use `clear perme` before you change its size.

Comment: @pm89 thank you, it works now after clearing, thanks again for your helping